# Retrieve last results leftJoined query ASC SQL

Tags: sql, left-join, sql-order-by

I have two left joined tables, users & posts

```
SELECT 
    p.post, u.user
FROM 
    posts p
LEFT JOIN 
    users u ON u.id_user = p.id_user
WHERE 
    p.id_user = 4 
ORDER BY 
    p.date DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

what I want to retrieve is in this order

```
     25 Mat -  Hi
     28 Mat -  How are you
     29 Mat - Hello
```

I've tried

```
SELECT *
    (QUERY) 
ORDER BY 
    p.date
```

but nothing, this new arrangement doesn't retrieve anything

How can I do that?

Comment: ORDER BY p.date ASC or ORDER BY p.date DESC

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT post, user
FROM (SELECT p.post, u.user
      FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
           users u
           ON u.id_user = p.id_user
      WHERE p.id_user = 4 
      ORDER BY p.date DESC
      LIMIT 3
     ) pu
ORDER BY post;
```

The subquery gets the *most recent* posts (as suggested by the title).  The outer query then orders these based on the first column (as suggested by the sample data).

Comment: So, post will replace p.post? And user to u.user?

Comment: @joe . . . In the outer query, you would need to use `pu`, because that is the alias of the subquery.